# How can I neaten the edge of my existing flat roof extension

Tags: exterior, roofing, asphalt, extension

[image]

It's an old roof and the asphalt was allowed to drip down the lead flashing leaving an ugly finish.

How can I neaten it up?

1. Can I trim it back so it's uniform?
2. Paint it white/ the colour of the wall?
3. Trim (hacksaw/grinder with diamond blade) and paint?
4. Fill / skim the gaps and paint?
5. Cover with flat roof drip edging?
6. What would you do?

Comment: 5. But I've never done it myself so let's see what the experts say.

Comment: Was it made that way or has the sun done it?

Comment: It was made that way.

Answer (score 2):

A rain gutter with a taller profile and mounted in the right place could conceal the roof edge.

If quirky design is your thing, that edge looks to me like it could be dressed up to look like icing spilling over a large flat cookie!